# npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND. Using npm install on OSX Yosemite

Tags: node.js, terminal, npm, osx-yosemite

attempting to install node.js and npm. Both are installed correctly but I keep on getting this error.

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to install `node` itself, or are you trying to install a node package using `npm install`?

Comment: I'm attempting to install a node package using npm

Comment: Do you have a recent version of node? Are you sure your internet is working, what package are you trying to install? Can you reproduce this problem on a different machine? It is really hard to guess at this as-is.

Comment: I have the most recent version of node. The internet is working and I am currently working on the most recent version of OSX Yosemite. When I type "npm install"  into terminal I get "npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND"

Comment: That error means that it's having a networking issue somehow. Have you set up any custom network settings for `npm` like proxies?